# Como passar uma variavel do controller pra view?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso passar a váriavel $limit para minha view e exibir ela lá, como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
public function index() {
    // ....
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; 
    $where = "id IS NOT NULL";
    $servidores = $this->server->listarServidores($this->select, $where, $limit, $offset);
    $data['servidores'] = $servidores;
    $this->template->load('template_view', 'home/home_view', $data);

}
```

Comment: Os dados na variável `$data` já não são passados para a view? Se sim, basta adicionar o valor de `$limit` em `$data`.

Comment: Sim, achei que o array $data era apenas pra passar resultados do banco, deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Coloquei a solução na forma de resposta, para que possa sinalizar o tópico como resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como definido na [documentação](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view) do framework, o método `load`, para carregar `views` e `templates` aceita um parâmetro do tipo `array` associativo com valores que estarão presentes na view/template.

Visto que no código apresentado já é feito o uso desta função através da variável `$data`, basta adicionar o valor de `$limit` neste array, como subsequente:

```
$data["limit"] = $limit;
```

Desta forma, o valor de `$limit` também estará acessível na view.

Comment: Era isso mesmo haha, valeu mesmo!